# Get value from JSON Array

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, getjson

My JSON currently looks like this:

```
 {
  "overview" : {
    "title" : "Blog"
  },

  "item" : {
    "title" : "Hello World"
  }

 }
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

      $.getJSON(url, function(obj) {

        $.each(obj, function(key, value){

          $('.image-slide-title').append(value.title);

        });

      });

});

</script>
```

All works perfectly fine except the HTML markup is showing:

```
<div class="image-slide-title">Blog Hello World</div>
```

I just want it to skip the **overview** key/value and just go right to the **item** key/value so at the end of the day it looks like:

```
 <div class="image-slide-title">Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could then loop through the `obj.item` properties:

```
for (var prop in obj.item) {
   var value = obj.item[prop];
   $('.image-slide-title').append(value);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to append .title onto the value

Comment: No, I didn't. It's not necessary. If you append that you no longer need to be looping through the properties because you are hardcoding the name of the property.